Why do my PHPUnit tests in NetBeans run but don't result in any code coverage?
I have Xdebug running and in mode xdebug.mode=develop,coverage. I checked this with phpinfo() and got:
Xdebug:
Development Helpers ✔ enabled
Coverage            ✔ enabled

I can run my tests, they work. If i do something stupid in my code, I get appropriate behaviour from the tests, so it is executed.
However, I get 0% code coverage, every line in my code is red (except the tests, they're not marked).
This is my current configuration.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="bootstrap.php" stopOnDefect="false">
    <php>
        <ini name="xdebug.mode" value="develop,coverage"/>
    </php>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">../_src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../_test</directory>
        </include>
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">../vendor</directory>
        </exclude>
    </source>
    <coverage includeUncoveredFiles="true">
        <report>
            <clover outputFile="../_reports/clover.xml"/>
            <cobertura outputFile="../_reports/cobertura.xml"/>
            <crap4j outputFile="../_reports/crap4j.xml" threshold="50"/>
        <html outputDirectory="../_reports/html-coverage" lowUpperBound="50" highLowerBound="90"/>
            <php outputFile="../_reports/coverage.php"/>
        <text outputFile="../_reports/coverage.txt" showUncoveredFiles="false" showOnlySummary="true"/>
            <xml outputDirectory="../_reports/xml-coverage"/>
        </report>
    </coverage>
    <logging>
        <junit outputFile="../_reports/junit.xml"/>
        <teamcity outputFile="../_reports/teamcity.txt"/>
        <testdoxHtml outputFile="../_reports/testdox.html"/>
        <testdoxText outputFile="../_reports/testdox.txt"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>

Can someone tell me what is possibly going wrong here…?

When I do this in PHPStorm it shows me the coverages directly at the sources and the methods itself. https://ibb.co/Ykgc6h4

When you run coverage tests phpunit create xml file with all informations about coverage. First thing is to verify that file exists and have valid data. Then check netbeans settings for coverage. There is an option to generate html report for coverage, validate if that works first.

@MarkusZeller: PhpStorm is fully wrapping the PHPUnit test runner, aligning PHP/Xdebug/PCov configuration so that it works on the coverage click. It's not 100% fail safe, but that's what the dedicated button is for. Not sure how this is in Netbeans, too long ago, so just an explanation how that coverage button works under the hood.

It's not entirely clear from your question where the configuration gap is, but this one clearly is wrong, and I'll explain afterwards why:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <ini name="xdebug.mode" value="develop,coverage"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>

While the PHPUnit configuration file supports this setting, and PHPUnit will call the ini_set() function for the ini directives name and value properly, the XDebug documentation elaborates further that the xdebug.mode directive needs to be set in the PHP startup phase (ref), that is for example on the command line:
php -d xdebug.mode=... -f vendor/bin/phpunit ...

As it is that mode is such a central setting for XDebug (new in 3), the often easier to configure option is the XDEBUG_MODE parameter (environment variable).
You can savely delete the <ini> element for name="xdebug.mode" from the PHPUnit configuration file. It is ineffective under standard operations, and may work when executing test cases in process separation (but there encoding other ini directives is limited in PHPUnit which can even bring more configuration gaps to the table). In short: There are better options.
Then check with the runner in Netbeans if you can either pass arguments to the PHP interpreter or set environment variables.
XDEBUG_MODE=develop,coverage

IIRC the environment parameter is most authoritative.
You should be able to find documentation about this in the XDebug manual.
For the general information about ini settings look for the Runtime Configuration section in the PHP manual, it covers the basic things the XDebug manual will build upon (as XDebug is a PHP extension).
For environment parameters in general (and henceforth PHP and XDebug will build upon), consult the manual of your preferred shell and your preferred operating system, then IDE.
